# How can I take input character in a character array using %c and produce the right output using %s?

Tags: arrays, c, string, output, character

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        int n, i;
        char ch[100];
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                scanf(" %c", &ch[i]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", strupr(ch));
        return 0;
}
```

At first, I want to take the size of the character array in n variable. After, i want to take n character's and assign the array. The output comes from this program is right but it also produce some garbage values.

For example:

```
5
s d g h f
Output: SDGHFC└U▄■`
```

How can i ignore the garbage values from my output?

Comment: in c/cpp a string needs to be ended with a '\0' character to identify end of string. you will need to add it manually after the loop at nth index. keeping this in mind you will have a boundary case when input 'n' itself is 100 & that will produce result similar to that u are getting now

Comment: Please try to give me a coding example!!! Thank You.

Comment: Please try to give me a coding example!!! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading character the spaces you are providing in your input, will also be considered as characters, and strupr(c) will give some shaggy output, also you have to manually provided null character at the end of your character array. Below program might help you find your answer

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        int n, i;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fflush(stdin);
        char ch[100];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                char temp;
                scanf("%c", &temp);
                if(temp != '\n')
                    ch[i] = temp;
                else
                    break;
        }
        ch[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", strupr(ch));
        return 0;
}
```

Your Input should look like

```
5
sdghf
```

To give input with spaces. Program will look like.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        int n, i;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fflush(stdin);
        char ch[100];
        char temp;
        i = 0;
        while(scanf("%c", &temp)){
                if(temp == ' ')
                    continue;
                if(temp != '\n')
                    ch[i++] = temp;
                else
                    break;
        }
        ch[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", strupr(ch));
        return 0;
}
```

Now, you can give your character in any arrangement as you want.

Comment: Is there any way to take the character input by using a space?? I mean character then space....and so on.

Comment: Is there any way to take the character input by using a space?? I mean character then space....and so on.

Comment: Yes, you can do so I am editing my answer for your request.

Comment: Note: `fflush(stdin);` is UB.

Comment: Thank You so very much. I got the answer. But fflush(stdin) is known for me. If you know, anything outside this, please describe for this problem.

Comment: For fflush(stdin), try to read this [tut](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-fflushstdin-c/#:~:text=Last%20Updated%3A%2013%2D12%2D,case%20of%20file%20output%20stream)

Comment: If, I successfully answered your question, you can up-vote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize your array ch[] to all zeros. I.E.

```
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) { ch[i] = '\0'; }
```

Put this line just after the declaration of ch[].

Comment: `char ch[100];` --> `char ch[100] = { 0 }` or `char ch[100] = ""` would do the same as _initialization_.  The `for()` loop is later _assignment_.